Why exception can not be caught on windows by msvc but on Linux by GCC
The same files on Windows and Linux as follow:
std_exp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        std::string s{nullptr};
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test001)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
message(STATUS "C++ compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "C++ compiler ID: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
message(STATUS "C++ compiler version: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}")
add_executable(test001 std_exp.cpp)

This is my compile commands.
comile commands
cmake -B ./build -S ./
cmake --build ./build/ --config Release

compiler output
On Windows:
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
-- C++ compiler: ${ROOT_PATH1}/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- C++ compiler ID: MSVC
-- C++ compiler version: 19.40.33812.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ${ROOT_PATH2}/build

On Linux:
-- C++ compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- C++ compiler ID: GNU
-- C++ compiler version: 11.4.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ${ROOT_PATH3}/build

The executable output on Linux
On Windows:
(no output)
On Linux:
std_exp.cpp15Caught exception: basic_string: construction from null is not valid

So why exp can not be caught on windows?

See dupe: What is happening when I initialize a std::string with 0?

The constructor of std::string that you are trying to use has undefined behavior if the argument isn't actually a pointer to a string. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string, specifically overload (9).
That one compiler happens to throw an exception while the other doesn't is completely reasonable outcome under undefined behavior, as is any other behavior at all.
As a side note: Starting with C++23 there is an extra overload (18) that will make a call with nullptr as argument to the constructor of std::string ill-formed.

The cppreference documentation actually mentions the case of using a null pointer to construct a std::string as a specific example of causing undefined behavior:

basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
(9)
(9) ...
The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid
range (for example, if s is a null pointer).

(emphasis is mine)
This is exactly what you do, and therefore it is UB (undefined behavior) and every outcome is valid.
Specifically each compiler is free to handle it as it see fit (including throwing an exception or any other way of handling).

cppreference is a good reference, but imho calling it "the documentation" is misleading.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai as I understand it, apart from the stadard itself, cppreference is considered to offer the best documentation for C++ (and that was my meaning). But anyway I updated and mentioned cppreference explicitly to avoid confusion.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It is about the best source of information on C++ that is still readable for most users (The C++ standard while more correct isn't as readable, and certainly lacks the canonical examples that cppreference has). So yes I too would consider it the defacto documentation for practical use.

@PepjinKramer "de facto" is still not "the documentation". Saying it is "the documentation" implies that it would be the only / the official, which it is not afaik. A bit wrong is still wrong and Imho it deserves better, calling it by the right name is already good enough. It is the best reference site I am aware of.

@PepijnKramer I actually agree with 463035818_is_not_an_ai
that "the documentation" implies the official one, which is why I editted to mention cpprefernce explicitly. But we all agree it is the best reference at the moment.
